# tf.decode_csv parameter 'labels' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: tensorflow

trying to pass TensorFlow tf.decode_csv a float64 datatype but getting error it's not allowed

```
    CSV_TYPES = [[0.0], [2.], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0]]
    def _parse_line(line):
        fields = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=CSV_TYPES)
```

The problem is the second value which here are my values for example

```
9.5,-110,9.5,50,68,1
9.5,+100,9.5,50,32,0
7,-110,7,30,24,1
7,-120,70,76,0
```

which produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'labels' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

saw a lot of discussion about this issue but could not figure out how to allow labels to have DataType float64 specifically

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that, I had an error in my .csv file.